# Playing youtube videos on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I was wondering how are apps like McTube (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mctube-for-youtube/id559618284?mt=8) playing youtube videos. It looks like a custom `MPMoviePlayerController` but is that allowed?

BTW I need autoplay which I couldn't achieve with `UIWebView`, that's why i was wondering.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some YouTube videos can be played back in a `MPMoviePlayerController` - some cannot. When you query a video through the YouTube Data API ([link here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Videos_feed)) you'll get back all the content types available for a particular videos, including the Flash player, 3GPP, MP4 (*if available*), etc. You can use these URLs to load up a `MPMoviePlayerController`.

This is perfectly fine, but as I've said - not all videos are available to embed this way. Some videos (mainly ones that require adverts to be displayed) can't be put into native controllers.

Comment: My concern was II/10 at https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms. However then it looks like they don't enforce it.